# Code crawler to crawl Asynchronous GA Code

Tags: php, google-code

Hello I have a php code crawler to detect a website if it has a Asynchronous Google Code. 
here's the snippet to detect the the asynch google Code:

```
$async_ga_string = "ga.async";

if(!strpos($str, $async_ga_string))$async_ga = '';
            else $async_ga = 'yes';
```

It works fine. But what I exactly needed is for me to able to get the asynch UA code in this google code snippet:

```
     var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2595901-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

I need to get the 'UA-2595901-1'

Comment: really don't have idea what to do know. Still figuring out myself. Thank you for your quick response @xbonez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an imperfect solution, but the Google Analytics Account ID is almost unique enough to find it using a simple Regular Expression:

```
<?php
$gaRegExp = '/UA-\d+-\d+/';

$testText = "var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2595901-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);"

preg_match( $gaRegExp , $testText , $matches )

// Returns, within the $matches variable, the following
// array (
//  0 => 'UA-2595901-1',
// )
```

Comment: where does $matches variable come from?

Comment: Hello is there also a regex for detecting a ga.async? instead of using strpos?

Comment: The above is a Regular Expression - it is not a `strpos`. Can you make your question clearer?